# Federated Learning for Image Captioning

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-federated

I'm relatively new to tensorflow, I've read a book about machine learning and I've took Udacity's course. I've been tasked with recreating the Image Captioning Model found on this tutorial https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/text/image_captioning using the Federated Learning library that tensorflow offers, so far everything is easy and I've managed to understand what I'm supposed to do until I reached the part of designing the model. In the federated learning tutorial (https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/tutorials/federated_learning_for_image_classification), In designing the variables part, how am i supposed to know the shape of the weights and bias?

Sorry if this is an obvious question but i've been struggling with shapes for quite sometime now, Thank you in advance! :)

EDIT: Sorry, I forgot to add this part to the question: How am I supposed to know the variables of my model? I know that the weights and bias are the base of the model along with the loss and the accuracy is for me to know how good the model performs, but is there anything else I need to know?

Answer (score 0):

The shapes of the weights and biases of the model are picked by the modeler/experiment (you :D). This is sometimes referred to as "picking a model architecture", and there is no silver bullet. The question has been answered fairly extensively in [How to decide neural network architecture?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/20222/how-to-decide-neural-network-architecture)

Comment: Oh, but in the case of image captioning, shouldn't the variables be the variables of the encoder + the decoder just like what the tutorial says? and if so, how can i know the shapes of these variables before the start of training?